# Maven/Spring/MVC Web app - error cannot TalendJob (third party Talend

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat7, talend

I'm developing a Spring/MVC/Maven Web app in Eclipse.  The use case is for the app to call Talend jobs on an adhoc basis with parameters.  The user enters time frame information (years, months) on a form page.  Everything worked (form, validation, model, configuration, error checking, etc) until I added the required Talend jars.

Some background -  I successfully created a simple Web app in Eclipse that has the same use case. For this app, I needed to place the Talend jars into the `WEB-INF\lib` folder.  For various reasons, I need to build a Web app that uses Spring/MVC/Maven technologies. I loaded all the required Talend jars into the `WEB-INF\lib` folder (exactly like I did with the previous Web app). I ran a successful Maven clean install. But running the embedded Tomcat (version 7.2.2) produced this error:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR: 
>   [ERROR]C:\Documents\TalendAdHoc\src\main\java\com\validator\UserValidator.java:[13]
>   error: package talenddev1.job_gl_master_ad_hoc_0_3 does not exist
>   [ERROR]
>   C:\Documents\TalendAdHoc\src\main\java\com\validator\UserValidator.java:[141,7]
>   error: cannot find symbol.

I then followed the steps from this site:

https://cleanprogrammer.net/adding-3rd-party-jar-to-maven-projects/

to add the third party jars to Maven projects (installed the jar into the local repository, added repository and dependency into the pom.xml, etc). Running the embedded Tomcat produced this error:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR:  [ERROR] 
>   C:\Documents\TalendAdHoc\src\main\java\com\validator\UserValidator.java:[155,16]
>   error: cannot access TalendJob

`

```
TalendJob` is located in the `UserValidator.java`:

    job_GL_Master_Ad_Hoc TalendJob=new job_GL_Master_Ad_Hoc(); 

String[] 
context=new String[] \{params...} 

TalendJob.runJob(context);
```

I realize this maybe a Talend issue so I've been also working with the Talend community as well.

Any support will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Here is my pom.xml

```
`<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>TalendAdHoc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
  <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JSTL Dependency -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
  <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Servlet Dependency -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- JSP Dependency -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.talend</groupId>
  <artifactId>job_gl_master_ad_hoc_0_3</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/lib/job_gl_master_ad_hoc_0_3.jar
  </systemPath>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.talend</groupId>
  <artifactId>job_gl_refresh_transaction_ad_hoc_0_2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>

 <systemPath>${project.basedir}
 /src/lib/job_gl_refresh_transaction_ad_hoc_0_2.jar
  </systemPath>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.talend</groupId>
  <artifactId>job_gl_load_transaction_ad_hoc_0_2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}
/src/lib/job_gl_load_transaction_ad_hoc_0_2.jar
  </systemPath>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.talend</groupId>
  <artifactId>job_gl_load_summary_ad_hoc_0_1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}
 /src/lib/job_gl_load_summary_ad_hoc_0_1.jar
  </systemPath>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.talend</groupId>
  <artifactId>job_gl_load_project_ad_hoc_0_1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}
  /src/lib/job_gl_load_project_ad_hoc_0_1.jar
  </systemPath>
</dependency>

</dependencies> 

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
    <fork>true</fork>
      <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\javac.exe
      </executable>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <!-- Embedded Apache Tomcat required for testing war -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <path>/</path>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>

  </plugins>
  </build>
  </project>`
```

And here is the UserValidator.java:

```
`package com.validator;

import java.util.Calendar;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.model.User; 

import talenddev1.job_gl_master_ad_hoc_0_3.job_GL_Master_Ad_Hoc;

@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return User.class.equals(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors err) {
    User user = (User) obj;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    set vars...

    validation code...

    error handling code...

    }

    job_GL_Master_Ad_Hoc talendJob = new job_GL_Master_Ad_Hoc();

    String[] context = new String[] { 
   "--context_param Host_Analytics_CurrentYear=" + currentYear,
            "--context_param Host_Analytics_CurrentYearStart=" +
    currentYearStart,
            "--context_param Host_Analytics_CurrentYearEnd=" + currentYearEnd,
            "--context_param Host_Analytics_PreviousYear=" + previousYear,
            "--context_param Host_Analytics_PreviousYearStart=" +
     previousYearStart,
            "--context_param Host_Analytics_PreviousYearEnd=" +
     previousYearEnd,
            "--context_param Host_Analytics_Transaction_Flag=" +
     transactionFlag,
            "--context_param Host_Analytics_Summary_Flag=" + summaryFlag,
            "--context_param Host_Analytics_Project_Flag=" + projectFlag };
     talendJob.runJob(context);

      }
    }`
```

Comment: Hi. Spring doesn't provide an embedded Tomcat, while Spring Boot does. Why are you adding jars by hand if you're using Maven?

Comment: Hi, I'm a newbie, so I created the web app from this site: http://boraji.com/spring-4-mvc-form-validation-example-using-validator-interface and then modified it to meet my use case, etc

Comment: I would suggest to take a look into spring boot and their documentation for a web application...

Comment: No problem, let's try to figured it out. First, do you know how maven works? Can you add you pom.xml file to your question?

Comment: Ok, I added my pom.xml and UserValidator.java